# Matrice help: Finding average without the zeros

Tags: r, montecarlo

I'm creating a Monte Carlo model using R. My model creates matrices that are filled with either zeros or values that fall within the constraints. I'm running a couple hundred thousand n values thru my model, and I want to find the average of the non zero matrices that I've created. I'm guessing I can do something in the last section.

Thanks for the help!

Code:

```
n<-252500

PaidLoss_1<-numeric(n)
PaidLoss_2<-numeric(n)
PaidLoss_3<-numeric(n)
PaidLoss_4<-numeric(n)
PaidLoss_5<-numeric(n)
PaidLoss_6<-numeric(n)
PaidLoss_7<-numeric(n)
PaidLoss_8<-numeric(n)
PaidLoss_9<-numeric(n)



for(i in 1:n){
claim_type<-rmultinom(1,1,c(0.00166439057698873, 0.000810856947763742, 0.00183509730283373, 0.000725503584841243, 0.00405428473881871, 0.00725503584841243, 0.0100290201433936, 0.00529190850119495, 0.0103277569136224, 0.0096449300102424, 0.00375554796858996, 0.00806589279617617, 0.00776715602594742, 0.000768180266302492, 0.00405428473881871, 0.00226186411744623, 0.00354216456128371, 0.00277398429498122, 0.000682826903379993))

claim_type<-which(claim_type==1)

claim_Amanda<-runif(1, min=34115, max=2158707.51)
claim_Bob<-runif(1, min=16443, max=413150.50)
claim_Claire<-runif(1, min=30607.50, max=1341330.97)
claim_Doug<-runif(1, min=17554.20, max=969871)


if(claim_type==1){PaidLoss_1[i]<-1*claim_Amanda}
if(claim_type==2){PaidLoss_2[i]<-0*claim_Amanda}
if(claim_type==3){PaidLoss_3[i]<-1* claim_Bob}
if(claim_type==4){PaidLoss_4[i]<-0* claim_Bob}
if(claim_type==5){PaidLoss_5[i]<-1* claim_Claire}
if(claim_type==6){PaidLoss_6[i]<-0* claim_Claire}




}

PaidLoss1<-sum(PaidLoss_1)/2525
PaidLoss3<-sum(PaidLoss_3)/2525
PaidLoss5<-sum(PaidLoss_5)/2525
PaidLoss7<-sum(PaidLoss_7)/2525
```

[partial output of my numeric matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgq9S.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, let me make sure I've wrapped my head around what you want to do: you have several columns -- in your example, `PaidLoss_1`, ..., `PaidLoss_9`, which have many entries. Some of these entries are 0, and you'd like to take the average (within each column) of the entries that are *not* zero. Did I get that right?

If so:

**Comment 1**: At the very end of your code, you might want to avoid using `sum` and dividing by a number to get the mean you want. It obviously *works*, but it opens you up to a risk: if you ever change the value of `n` at the top, then in the best case scenario you have to edit several lines down below, and in the worst case scenario you forget to do that. So, I'd suggest something more like `mean(PaidLoss_1)` to get your mean.

Right now, you have `n` as 252500, and your denominator at the end is 2525, which has the effect of inflating your mean by a factor of 100. Maybe that's what you wanted; if so, I'd recommend `mean(PaidLoss_1) * 100` for the same reasons as above.

**Comment 2**: You can do what you want via subsetting. Take a smaller example as a demonstration:

```
test <- c(10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0)
mean(test)                           # gives 5
test!=0                              # a vector of TRUE/FALSE for which are nonzero
test[test!=0]                        # the subset of test which we found to be nonzero
mean(test[test!=0])                  # gives 10, the average of the nonzero entries
```

The middle three lines are just for demonstration; the only necessary lines to do what you want are the first (to declare the vector) and the last (to get the mean). So your code should be something like `PaidLoss1 <- mean(PaidLoss_1[PaidLoss_1 != 0])`, or perhaps that times 100.

**Comment 3**: You might consider organizing your stuff into a dataframe. Instead of typing `PaidLoss_1`, `PaidLoss_2`, etc., it might make sense to organize all this `PaidLoss` stuff into a matrix. You could then access elements of the matrix with `[ , ]` indexing. This would be useful because it would clean up some of the code and prevent you from having to type lots of things; you could also then make use of things like the `apply()` family of functions to save you from having to type the same commands over and over for different columns (such as the mean). You could also use a dataframe or something else to organize it, but having *some* structure would make your life easier.

(And to be super clear, your code is exactly what my code looked like when I first started writing in R. You can decide if it's worth pursuing some of that optimization; it probably just depends how much time you plan to eventually spend in R.)